# How to redirect subdomains without specify the domain?

Tags: ubuntu, dns

Is there a way to redirect all my subdomains without specify the domain, I mean for example:

when I write `www` it should resolve to `www.mydomain.com` or if I write `ftp` it should redirect to `ftp.mydomain.com`

I know I could write wildcards in the hosts file but I'm not sure how to write something where the wildcard take the subdomain and concatenate it with `mydomain.com`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If www.mydomain.com already has correct dns info, you only have to add mydomain.com as a DNS search domain. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135629/how-to-add-some-additional-dns-search-domains-without-ignoring-the-ones-returned) for information on how to do it on Ubuntu.

Comment: I've done what it says, but I'm not sure it's working... How could I know?

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out, I haven't restarted the network, thanks buddy!